Import .md files dynamically by slug
i am pretty new to Astro, and i want to find out how to have a file such as [...slug] read md files based on that slug. Best with using collection entries or something similar. It seems there is no easy way because Javascript does not know how to import them first.
Almost everything possible in the documentation.

what do you mean with "Almost everything possible in the documentation."? yes, please see the docs. if you still have questions, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
